# How to fix translation error (NoSuchMethodError: The getter)?

Tags: flutter, translation

Recently i started to want to update my app to be multilingue, but i got stuck in this problem:

[Problem Print Screen](https://prnt.sc/zv6evh)

Im using l10n method.

Here's the code im using to translate:

**Translation Files**

[Print #1](https://prnt.sc/100o5kj)

**Body Code exemple i made to make translation**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'generated/l10n.dart';
//and some more that its not necessary to paste here...

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final color = Colors.white;
    _scale = 1 - _controller.value;
    return new WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.delegate.supportedLocales,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(28, 28, 28, 100),
              body: Center(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30.0,
                    ),
                    DelayedAnimation(
                      child: new Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context).erro_loginmsg,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 15.0, color: color),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      delay: delayedAmount + 1000,
                    ),
```

**Here's more information about the problem**

```
The getter 'erro_loginmsg' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: erro_loginmsg

The relevant error-causing widget was
VerificationPage
lib\main.dart:60
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _MyAppState.build
package:timeaccessapp/MenuLogin.dart:444
#2      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4744
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4627
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4800
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**Flutter Doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.804], locale pt-PT)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

i Have no idea of the problem, tested everything and still not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your locale code like this.

```
void main() async {
  var delegate = await LocalizationDelegate.create(
      fallbackLocale: 'hi', supportedLocales: ['en', 'es', 'pt', 'fr']);
  Color color = mainColor;
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
      create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(color),
      child: LocalizedApp(
        delegate,
        App(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppState myAppState = new _AppState();

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeColor = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
    var localizationDelegate = LocalizedApp
        .of(context)
        .delegate;
    return MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          localizationDelegate
        ],
        supportedLocales: localizationDelegate.supportedLocales,
        locale: localizationDelegate.currentLocale,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: Strings.app_title,
        theme: ThemeData(
            pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
              TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
            }),
            primaryColor: Colors.blue,
            textTheme: TextTheme(
                bodyText2: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                bodyText1: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ))),
        localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
          for (var supportedLocaleLanguage in supportedLocales) {
            if (supportedLocaleLanguage.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
                supportedLocaleLanguage.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
              return supportedLocaleLanguage;
            }
          }
          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
        home: components()
    );
  }

  Widget components() {
    return Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(translate('hello_trans'),
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        color: color),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )
                ]
            )
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Dindt work.. the code i have is probably working.. my guess is that the way im building the:   Widget build(BuildContext context) or class VerificationPage extends StatefulWidget  is the problem ? idk.. im kinda lost

Comment: @NunoMonteiro Provide complete code here.